# AngularJS Multiselect checkbox dropdown Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pop-up with multi-select drop down.

Multi-Select Dropdown Code

```
<select name="edit_tags" class="form-control" id="advisor_article_tagsx" multiple="" 
   required ng-model="article_selected" ng-options="article_service as article_service.name for article_service in article_services">
</select>
```

There is an array `article_services` which is used in multi-select, I am fetching this array from below code.

```
$http.get(url + 'service_provided').
     then(function (response) {
         $scope.article_services = response.data.service_provided;
         //$scope.article_selected = [$scope.article_services[0], $scope.article_services[1]];
});
```

Now I want that when I click on Edit Button with `ng-click="advisor_article_edit()"` to open pop-up, my multi-select checkbox comes with some selection.
I want that Select must be work in below function but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
$scope.advisor_article_edit = function () {
        // I need selection work from here. But it doesn't.
        $scope.article_selected = [$scope.article_services[3]];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, like in the snippet.:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.cars = [{id:1, name: 'Audi'}, {id:2, name: 'BMW'}, {id:1, name: 'Honda'}];
  $scope.advisor_article_edit = function () {       
        $scope.article_selected = [$scope.cars[1]];
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
<select name="edit_tags" class="form-control" id="advisor_article_tagsx" multiple="" 
   required ng-model="article_selected" ng-options="car as car.name for car in cars">
</select>

<button ng-click="advisor_article_edit()">Edit</button><br>
Selected : {{article_selected}}
</div>
```

[Working Plunkar Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/zowE9jjABD6mk7pDT1lB?p=preview)

Comment: I am trying like this. https://plnkr.co/edit/N8DOFmrfIQiNedAlnaK2?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to trigger the click:

```
var cb = angular.element('some-selector');
cb.triggerHandler('click');
```

This should be done in a directive as it's dom manipulation

Comment: If you don't mind then can you give complete solution here ??

Comment: I can't as I'm at work but if you create a jsFiddle or CodePen or something with your issue I can try to fix it